# Rewrite folder as root - but also subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, root, subdirectory

I'm rewriting myfolder as root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)myfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myfolder/$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't work for inner folders.
I Also want mydomain.com/myfolder/images
to work as mydomain.com/images

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!myfolder/).*)$ /myfolder/$1 [L,NC]
```